# How to decrease the padding of dock icons in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, ubuntu-dock, dock, dash-to-dock

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I don't know how I did this, but I tried to customize my dock settings using dash to dock extension. But then I realized that the space between 2 icons on the dock is too much and I don't like it. I need the default values. There isn't any option in the dconF-editor also. As you can see in these images, there is a huge space between my dock icons. Is there any method to correct this?

This is how my dock appears

[image: This is how my dock appears]

This is the default dock

[image: This is the default dock]

Comment: you can reset easily in dconf-editor... https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHEB7.png

Comment: @PRATAP I did it but nothing happens :(

Comment: seems shell theme is controlling it then.. can you change any shell theme n see..

Comment: I changed the theme. But the width of the dock doesn't change. It seems like for lower dock icon sizes the width doesnt reduce much. So I am using 22 ptx, and I think its normal for such a size.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this following these two steps described below -

1. **Change dashToDock extension setting -**

   a. open dconf editor

   b. go to `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`

   c. turn on custom-theme-shrink
2. **Now you have to change theme css file -**

   a. now go to `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/`

   *(I'm assuming that you are using Yaru-dark shell theme)*

   b. open gnome-shell.css file in a text editor

   c. search these lines of code -

   ```
   #dashtodockContainer.shrink .dash-item-container > StButton, #dashtodockContainer.dashtodock .dash-item-container > StButton {
   padding: 2px 4px !important; }
   ```

   d. change padding to -

   ```
   padding: 0px 0px !important;
   ```

Now restart your gnome-shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then running **`r`** command

Comment: Good answer. Although, answer's a little bit incomplete/pre-assuming. It assumes that the user uses "Yaru-dark" as their shell theme. You should go to "Gnome Tweaks", and see which shell theme you're using, and then go to `/usr/share/theme/<your-gnome-shell-theme>/<gnome-shell.css or gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css>`. Also, `#dashtodockContainer` is not the correct selector anymore from what I see. `#dash` is what is used in my css file

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a theme go to
/home/{user}/.themes/{theme name}/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css

or for system theme go to
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme

find this line of code

```
  #dashtodockContainer .show-apps .overview-icon {
  padding: 4px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

and change padding to whichever value suits you. Log out and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using dash to dock extension put this at the bottem of gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/stylesheet.css

```
#dashtodockContainer .overview-icon {
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
}

#dashtodockContainer.icon {
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
border-radius: 0px;/*for square border */
}
```

then reload using alt+f2 and r

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/bw2cbr/is_there_a_way_to_further_shrink_the_dock_from/epw6pu0/)

Also change the outermost border using

```
#dashtodockContainer.shrink .dash-item-container > StButton,
#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock .dash-item-container > StButton {
padding: 1px 2px; /* padding between icon borders */
}
```